# iTunes rapidly cycles through my songs

Tags: windows, itunes

On my Windows Vista machine I have iTunes 9.2.0.  Today I opened it and clicked on a song.  Instead of playing it, iTunes just started cycling through my song list upwards (towards the top of my list).  No song will play, it is going that fast.  I upgraded to 9.2.1 and the same thing happens.  This will happen on any song.  I did not change any settings before hand.  The funny thing is my wife's iTunes (on another machine - Vista) started to do the same thing about a week ago.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you still have the songs there? This normally happens if iTunes fails to find the files.

Comment: Absolutely.  If while it is cycling through my music, I open up a window (take focus away from iTunes), whatever song it was on at that moment starts playing like normal.  It is just when iTunes has focus that it starts to go wonky.

Comment: In that case, just nuke iTunes and start fresh. I know it's not exactly the most elegant solution, but it usually works.

Comment: That seems to have done it.  Please enter an actual answer and I will accept it.  Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstalling iTunes. That usually does the trick and is usually the fastest way of solving such problems.

Comment: I just discovered that it is doing it again.  Perhaps I should get rid of iTunes completely and just use something else...

Comment: @Dan I don't know. I've had a lot of problems with iTunes, sadly, including it failing to see my iPod. I can't really say there's a fix for any of its problems. On a Mac it's great, but Apple doesn't really seem to know (or care) how to make great software on Windows...

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Can't find the source of it either. Music is stored in a sound location which doesn't require refreshing the library. iTunes isn't 'looking' for the music, just outright ignores it, maybe plays 1/10 of a second of noise, then carries on.

Problem is, I'm getting this with iTunes, Windows Media Player, WinAmp etc. I'm thinking it is potentially a hardware error, permissions error or something within the files is now outdated etc.

Annoying...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need iTunes for syncing with your iPod (say you don't have one) or just looking for a music player for the desktop, I would give the **[Zune Software](http://zune.net/en-US/)** a try...it is faster than iTunes, and I like listening to music on my PC much better on the Zune Software...free, no Zune required...